# Official template for Marketing Cloud blueprint document

Tags: marketing-cloud

I am wondering if there is an official template for what structure a Salesforce Marketing Cloud blueprint should look like?

**UPDATE**: Down from the depth of my archives, I found a blueprint document that template-wise follows all Salesforce brand theme (logos, colors, fonts etc). I am wondering if this is based on an official document by Salesforce or was it just made to look like one?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you’re talking about the blueprint or solution overview documentation from [Salesforce Marketing Cloud services](https://www.salesforce.com/services/advisory-services/marketing-cloud-services/) then that would depend on the solution provided. Typically it contains:

1. User stories
2. Methodology
3. Configuration specifications
4. Delivery
5. User acceptable testing

But it’s not likely anyone would share an “official” template with you.

Comment: Please look at the update on the question! I am just making sure whether the template belongs to Salesforce or was it just made to look like one?

Comment: Yes that belongs to Salesforce Marketing Cloud. Looks like an old one.

Comment: OK, so where do I find the latest template? I'm not trying to use the text, just the template.

Comment: You don't. It's not publicly available.

Comment: Ok, thank you! I don't understand why a Word template should be this secret, though.